# How to send a signal to a process in C?

Tags: c, signals

I need to send a signal to a process and when the process receives this signal it does some things, how is this best achieved in C?

Answer (score 27):

The way to send a signal to a process is `kill(pid, signal);` However, you should be aware that signals are not a robust means of inter-process communication except for parent-to-direct-child messages due to inherent race conditions. Pipes, files, directories, named semaphores, sockets, shared memory, etc. all provide greatly superior approaches to inter-process communication.

Comment: Which header file defines kill?

Comment: It's declared in `<signal.h>`

Comment: Is it standard C or POSIX? I am confused because wikipedia page for signal.h does not include kill also C in a Nutshell book does not mention this function.

Comment: Plain C does not have processes, so it has no way to a send a signal to a process. In plain C you can signal yourself with `raise`. Processes and the functions to act on them come from POSIX.

Comment: The idea comes to me to send a Signal to `Audacity` while for example browsing on the web recording my voice reading

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be on one of the Unix variants, the following man pages will help:

```
man 2 kill
man 2 signal
man 2 sigvec
```

Answer (score 0):

**`kill` + `fork` runnable POSIX example**

Time for some fun:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h> /* false */
#include <stdio.h> /* perror */
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* wait, sleep */
#include <unistd.h> /* fork, write */

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char s1[] = "SIGUSR1\n";
    char s2[] = "SIGUSR2\n";
    if (sig == SIGUSR1) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, s1, sizeof(s1));
    } else if (sig == SIGUSR2) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, s2, sizeof(s2));
    }
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;

    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGUSR2, signal_handler);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        assert(false);
    } else {
        if (pid == 0) {
            while (1);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        while (1) {
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            sleep(1);
            kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -std=c99 signal_fork.c
./a.out
```

Outcome:

```
SIGUSR1
SIGUSR2
SIGUSR1
SIGUSR2
....
```

But beware that there are many complexities when dealing with signals:

- only certain functions can be called from signal handlers: [Why only async-signal-safe functions can be called from signal handlers safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467694/why-only-async-signal-safe-functions-can-be-called-from-signal-handlers-safely)
- different functions have different behaviors when interrupted by signals: `man 7 signal`, `SA_RESTART`
- global variables can only be accessed from the signal handler if they have type `sig_atomic_t`: [How does sig_atomic_t actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931456/how-does-sig-atomic-t-actually-work)

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10, [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/89587a5ae1a912523fc691606d55d7fea9490d03/posix/interactive/signal_fork.c).