# Why and how this C code can produce an Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

I have written the following code, but want to know why this program is exhibiting different behavior with compiler optimization

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

unsigned int counter = 0;

void *thread0_func(void *arg)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    printf("Thread 0\n");
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(3);
        counter++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void action_handler(int sig_no)
{
    printf("SigINT Generated: %d\n",counter);
    counter += 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread_id[2];

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = action_handler;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL))
        perror("Cannot Install Sig handler");


    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL, thread0_func, NULL))
    {
        perror("Error Creating Thread 0");
    }
    else
    {

    }
    while(counter == 0);
    printf("Counter: %d\n", counter);

//  pthread_join(thread_id[0], NULL);
    
    return (0);
}
```

Under normal compilation condition (without optimization), ie. `gcc example.c -o example -pthread` the program works as per the expected logic written i.e. the program waits on the instruction `while(counter == 0);` for variable `counter` value to become non zero either from thread or from signal handler, then, loop breaks and the program prints the value and exit.

If the code is compiled with `gcc -O3 example.c -o example -pthread`, then the program keeps running and incrementing the value from thread as well as whenever signal handler gets executed.

```
$ ./example 
Thread 0
^CSigINT Generated: 4
^CSigINT Generated: 6
^CSigINT Generated: 8
^CSigINT Generated: 9
^CSigINT Generated: 11
^CSigINT Generated: 12
```

But some people says that this code is not compliant and will produce a UB across different platforms!

Comment: sounds like it does and you saw this when it doesn't stop with -O3. I'll let someone who knows the rules better explain why

Comment: The code doesn't "produce" undefined behavior. A subset of the behavior of a program which behavior is undefined is the correct behavior. And as such showing that a program operates correctly is not a proof against it. If a program exhibits undefined behavior, that means it _can_ break, not that it will always break.

Comment: My guess is that your loop is "optimized" to `if ( counter==0) while(1);`

Comment: At least add `volatile`: `volatile unsigned int counter = 0;`.

Comment: The update of `counter` in one thread with a read of `counter` in another thread is a data race, and data races are undefined behavior (according to the C11 memory model).

Comment: `But some people says` Who exactly? Did you ask them?

Comment: One way to avoid data races is using mutexes (see the `pthread_mutex_init` and `pthread_mutex_lock` functions). Another way is using atomic integers (available in C11 and later, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Comment: `while(counter == 0);` is undefined behavior, nothing is happening in the loop. `sigaction(SIGINT, &sa` is using indeterminate values from `sa`, which most probably results in undefined behavior. `sa` is not initialized fully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void action_handler(int sig_no)
{
    printf("SigINT Generated: %d\n",counter);
    counter += 1;
}
```

The signal handler invokes undefined behaviour because it calls an [async-signal-unsafe function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

From the C standard:

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.14.1.1 The signal function ¶5 If the signal
> occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise
> function, **the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to
> any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a
> lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object
> declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or the signal handler calls any
> function in the standard library other than the abort function, the
> _Exit function, the quick_exit function**, or the signal function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the
> signal that caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such
> a call to the signal function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value
> of errno is indeterminate.252)

Furthermore, it modifies a variable that is not of type `volatile sigatomic_t`.

The first problem can be eliminated by using the `write()` system call (POSIX defines it to be async-signal-safe), and the latter by declaring the variable as:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t counter;
```

That is not all!

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = action_handler;
```

The `sa struct` was never fully initialised, only the `sa_handler` member was. The rest of the members remain uninitialised and have indeterminate values. The call to `sigaction()` is then passed an uninitialized `struct` which would presumably invoke undefined behaviour.¹ — @KamilCuk

Either use an explicit initializer to zero it out:

```
struct sigaction sa = { 0 };
```

Or alternatively, use `memset()`.

There may still be some other problems with your code.

Comment: Thanks! I found this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931456/how-does-sig-atomic-t-actually-work