# atomic operation with glibc C different from _Atomic

Tags: c, posix, atomic, gnu, glibc

According to [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html),

> [we] can assume that `int` is atomic. You can also assume that pointer types are atomic...Both of these assumptions are true on all of the machines that the GNU C Library supports and on all POSIX systems we know of.

Given this, I prepared a test like below on Linux:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Atomic int acnt = 0;
int cnt = 0;
sig_atomic_t scnt = 0;

void *adding(void *input) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    ++acnt;
    ++cnt;
    ++scnt;
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
  pthread_t tid[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, adding, NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

  printf("the value of acnt is %d\n", acnt);
  printf("the value of cnt is %d\n", cnt);
  printf("the value of scnt is %d\n", scnt);
  return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, the results are typically like these:

```
the value of acnt is 100000
the value of cnt is 49723
the value of scnt is 52380
```

Why aren't `cnt` and `scnt` 100000 too? Isn't that they can be guaranteed to be atomic? I can think of one reason, perhaps "accessing" and "modifying" `int` is atomic, but "++int" is not?

Comment: You are misinterpreting what the link says. You can't pretend that `int`s are atomics in the multithreading sense. The link is only about atomicity of `volatile int` access with regard to signal handlers on the same thread (and only on the mentioned GNU systems).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931456/how-does-sig-atomic-t-actually-work  including the comments - " C prior of C11 didn't have even a model of threads, so the type sig_atomic_t of the C standard made no assumption at all if this could be suited for multithreading."

Comment: *Isn't that they can be guaranteed to be atomic?* Because atomic RMWs are a lot more expensive, so compilers don't do that when not required.  They also optimize away loads and stores on plain `int` in ways that are safe for code without data-race UB, which makes single-threaded code *much* faster than debug builds where everything is sort of like volatile.

Comment: @user17732522 where is the `volatile` part from? The link does not mention `volatile`.

Comment: @DaveS then what is the atomicity of `int`/`sig_atomic_t` good for? For signal handling and definitely nothing more?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind It is kind of implied. `sig_atomic_t` also isn't useful without `volatile`. Without `volatile` there is no guarantee that a write in C code actually translates to a store in machine instructions at all.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Yes, `volatile sig_atomic_t` (and `volatile int` if you want) is only useful for interaction with signal handlers. For concurrency you always need actual `_Atomic` types (or mutices).

Comment: @user17732522 okay, this is also a point I am not sure. Do you mean that `volatile int` is ONLY useful for signal handling? If so, does C standard or POSIX standard mention that the signal handler always lives in the same thread? So we can have sort of "multithreading" within a thread?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind To which thread signals are delivered is a complicated topic in itself. The C standard itself makes no guarantee. POSIX offers functionality to disable delivery of signals on certain threads by blocking signals, but there is still a lot unspecified. Linux etc. have further specific functionality that may be preferred over the POSIX one.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: *where is the volatile part from? The link does not mention volatile.* Yeah, the glibc manual should really get updated to mention `volatile` when talking about what's guaranteed.  It all traces back to the ISO C standard which gives some consistency guarantees between a thread and signal handlers that interrupt that thread, for `volatile sig_atomic_t` but nothing else (except lock-free atomics, which you can order with `atomic_signal_fence` which is cheaper than `atomic_thread_fence`, only having to give compile-time ordering, not inter-thread run-time ordering.)

Comment: And yes, a signal handler runs asynchronously wrt. to the thread it interrupted.  Exactly like an interrupt handler wrt. other code on the same CPU core for an OS kernel.  Under most POSIX OSes, a signal could be delivered between any two asm instructions, so any C read or write that takes multiple asm instructions could be "torn" across the signal handler.  `volatile sig_atomic_t` guarantees this won't happen, and being `volatile` it can't reorder much (at least not with respect to other visible side effects) or optimize away or get hoisted or sunk out of loops.

Comment: Also, yes, `++scnt` isn't atomic even wrt. signal handlers, even for `volatile sig_atomic_t`.  It's a separate load and store.  C++ removed `++` and `--` from `volatile` because apparently it wasn't obvious or well-known enough that it's just short-hand for two separate accesses, not a single RMW access.  Or that it's ambiguous what it even *should* mean.  Ironically, `volatile` will IIRC prevent GCC or clang (I forget which) from using x86 `add [mem], 1` as a single instruction, which would be atomic wrt. interrupts (and thus signals).  (Only CISC ISAs tend to have a single-instruction RMW)

Comment: See [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) for more; that's linked from my answer on the linked duplicate, but a lot of people don't bother to follow links.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, your link is very helpful and exactly what I want to know

Comment: @user17732522 as you mentioned the glibc's doc, I have anther question. [This link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html) only mentions `int`, does glibc's doc mean to say all integer type or only `int` type, excluding even `int32_t`, `uint32_t` etc? Do you have any source on this?

Comment: @PeterCordes one thing I also want to confirm is this: say I have`uint32_t a = 0` and I assign new value to it: `a = 0xFFFFFFFF`. If I access `a`, it is impossible for me to read something like `0xFFFFFF00`/`0xFFFF0000`/`0x00FFFF00`/`0x0000FF00`/etc, meaning that assignment and access should always be "atomic", there is never an intermediary state that can be observed by my program. Is this correct?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are aliases, not distinct types. Whether they are `int` and `unsigned int` respectively may be architecture-dependent. I would assume that `unsigned int` is guaranteed to have the same properties as `int` even if the documentation doesn't mention it explicitly. This is normally a property of the size of the type, not the value interpretation. But that's just my assumption. I would not rely on these guarantees anyway. Given that there are proper atomic types, `sig_atomic_t` and signal fences, you don't have to rely on `volatile int` for signal handlers.

Comment: @user17732522 so you mean to say, glibc's doc does not make this clear and unlike the previous comment (in which you think glibc doc's `int` must be `volatile int`), this time you believe we can not draw further conclusion in absence of the glibc's explicit statement. Is this correct?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind The documentation is imprecise either way. This is the libc documentation, but whether or not these guarantees are satisfied is a matter of the compiler. They are probably assuming that you have a full GNU system with GCC compiler, making assumption about how it handles `volatile` access and which architectures it supports, and I wouldn't bet that "_and on all POSIX systems we know of_" is up-to-date either. I am just interpreting based on how compilers generally work and what related behavior the standard specifies.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Regarding your comment to PeterCordes: You still need `volatile uint32_t` for this to generally be satisfied, not only for reordering, but also for the value tearing. As far as I know GCC may e.g. replace consecutive stores to contiguous memory with a `memset` call which in turn may store in smaller than `int` size stores, which would permit tearing. I (hope) `volatile` prevents that, but again that's really a question for the compiler (GCC). PeterCordes may correct me on that if I am wrong. In any case, these guarantees apply only relative to a signal handler on the same thread.

Comment: (Accidentally mismatched `uint32_t` and `int` in the above. As I said there may be GNU-supported platforms where `uint32_t` is larger than `int` and the guarantee doesn't apply to `uint32_t` to begin with. And of course, just to make sure again, everything we are discussing here, except for `volatile sig_atomic_t`, is not standardized in any way and certainly doesn't need to hold on non-GNU systems.)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: All integer types: no, an obvious counter-example is `long long` (or any typdefs for it like `int64_t`) on 32-bit architectures like ARM or x86-32.  Even with `volatile`, GCC doesn't choose to access it with a single instruction (because that would require bouncing the data through vector registers, even if they're available.)  It does that for `_Atomic int64_t`, though.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y9b3PzT49

Comment: That glibc manual page is just confusing and basically wrong due to the omission of `volatile`, and talking about atomicity without being more explicit that they only mean *with respect to interrupts*, not other cores.  Making sure read or write accesses are done atomically for types up to `uintptr_t` or actual pointers only happens with `volatile`, as shown in [Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71866535)  (@user17732522)

Comment: (Well actually that AArch64 `stp` for uint64_t shown in the linked Q&A *is* one insn, so it is atomic wrt. interrupts, but only ARMv8.4-a guarantees it across cores.  GCC does seem to go out of its way to support `volatile` as a roll-your-own-atomic for types up to register width, since the Linux kernel relies on this.)

Comment: A more accurate statement for that glibc page would be: in addition to `volatile sig_atomic_t` having guarantees wrt. signal handlers, GNU systems have the same guarantees for `volatile int`, `volatile intptr_t`, and `volatile` pointers. And also, as GCC de-facto behaviour which the Linux kernel relies on, load and store atomicity across threads (but no ordering guarantees, unlike `_Atomic`, and no atomic RMWs.)  They might also be trying to say that if plain `int` happens to be visible at all between a thread and signal handler despite the UB, it won't be torn.

Comment: See also https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/ - Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?
 - don't use memory barriers like `asm("" ::: "memory")` around non-`volatile` int accesses to force them to happen; use volatile to make sure a load is exactly one access, not for example inventing another later load and optimizing away the temporary you loaded into in the source.

Comment: @PeterCordes "_They might also be trying to say that if plain int happens to be visible at all between a thread and signal handler despite the UB, it won't be torn._": But I don't think they really can guarantee this without `volatile`, which is what I was suggesting in my last comment. Does the GCC guarantee that a plain `int` write will never split into two instructions? Does glibc guarantee that none of the built-in functions like `memcpy` (which the compiler may invent calls to) will try to copy smaller than `int` chunks on `int`-aligned arguments?

Comment: Also, with plain `int`, without `volatile`, can't there be scenarios in which a speculative store can occur that shouldn't ever be visible to the signal handler? (e.g. `if(b) x = 0; else x = 1;` -> `x = 0; if(!b) x = 1;` transformation)

Comment: @user17732522: I should have added that if the documentation *was* trying to say anything about non-`volatile` int, that would be an even bigger mistake, and even more in need of an edit, because I wouldn't want to bet on it being *always* true, even limited to GNU systems using glibc + GCC.  It might well be the case, but verifying that would require going through tons of code to look for possibilities similar to that AArch64 u64 `stp` case (but with two actual stores), and every `memcpy` impl for every ISA.  x86-64 is fine; for sizes 4-7 bytes, it does two (partially) overlapping 4-byte mov.

Comment: @user17732522: And yes, "out-of-thin-air" values might become possible if GCC ever does that valid optimization for objects that are written with different values in opposite sides of a branch.   (BTW, the memcpy case for sizes 4-7 is https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S.html#293 .  Size 12 for example would do two overlapping 8-byte loads then stores. But yeah, different tuning choices on different ISAs might be different. Or if it ever chooses to use x86 `rep movsb` on CPUs where that's supposed to be fast, but the ucode uses a slow strat)

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes , I read some of your posts. One more question: Does C have something like `std::memory_order`? Or this is not something C standard specified?

Comment: Yeah, C11 `<stdatomic.h>` provides exactly the same functionality as C++11 `<atomic>`, but without a class wrapper or convenient overloads of the same name for optional extra args.  So you have to do `atomic_load_explicit(&my_atomic_int,  memory_order_acquire)`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread